# How is GRU outputting the following values?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

When I run the following code

```
from tensorflow import keras 
import numpy as np
x = np.ones((1,2,1))
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.GRU(
    units = 1, activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='sigmoid',
    use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='ones',
    recurrent_initializer='ones',bias_initializer='zeros', return_sequences = True))
model.predict(x)
```

I get the output => array([[[0.20482421],         [0.34675306]]], dtype=float32)

When I do this by hand I am getting 0.55

Assuming no biases and all weights are set to 1

hidden_(t-1) = 0

update_gate = sigmoid(1x1 + 1x0) = 0.73

relevance_gate = sigmoid(1x1 + 1x0) = 0.73

candidate_h(t) = tanh( 1 x (0 x 0.73) + 1 x 1) = tanh(1) = 0.76

h(t) = 0.73*0.76 + (1 - 0.73)x0 = 0.55

so shouldn't the first value of the output be 0.55?

Comment: You can look at the source here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py if you search for the file in your installation, you can debug it line by line and see where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have mistakenly swapped the equation in the last line for hidden state.

`sigmoid(1 * 1 + 1 * 0) = 0.73105857863, tanh(1 * 1 + 1 * 0) = 0.761594155956`

H<sub>t</sub> = Z<sub>t</sub> ⊙ H<sub>t-1</sub> + (1 - Z<sub>t</sub>) ⊙ H<sup>~</sup><sub>t</sub>

Since, H<sub>t-1</sub> = 0, this results in, H<sub>t</sub> = (1 - Z<sub>t</sub>) ⊙ H<sup>~</sup><sub>t</sub>

Following [the GRU formula](https://d2l.ai/chapter_recurrent-modern/gru.html#hidden-state) I got, `h(t) = 0.73105857863 * 0 + (1 - 0.73105857863) x 0.761594155956 = 0.20482421480989209117972` which matches output `0.20482421`.

For the next time step,

R<sub>t</sub> = Sigmoid(1 * 1 + 1 * 0.20482421) = `0.769381871687`

Z<sub>t</sub> = Sigmoid(1 * 1 + 1 * 0.20482421) = `0.769381871687`

H<sup>~</sup><sub>t</sub> = tanh(1 * 1 + 0.769381871687 * 0.20482421 * 1) = `0.8202522791`

H<sub>t</sub> = 0.769381871687 * 0.20482421 + (1 - 0.769381871687) * 0.8202522791 = `0.346753079407`

This matches with final output of `0.34675306`.

Reference,

https://d2l.ai/chapter_recurrent-modern/gru.html#hidden-state

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.GRU.html

Comment: Thank you so much! But this is very confusing, sources like courser and wikipedia are using the opposite formula en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gated_recurrent_unit, also found another topic that explained this https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17491/explaining-gru-equations-from-two-sources

Comment: One equation seems opposite of another. Here, in GRU equation on page 11, https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224n/readings/cs224n-2019-notes05-LM_RNN.pdf, the equation does not match wikipedia. Same for, GRU paper, page 12, section A.1, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.1078.pdf. Here, on page 4, section 3.2, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.3555.pdf, the equation mentioned in wikipedia. In d2l.ai it says, Whenever the update gate  Z_t  is close to 1, we simply retain the old state, H_t-1, but in the other equation is seems when update gate  Z_t  is close to 0, the old state, H_t-1 retained.

Comment: I see there are two types of equations for candidate hidden state used in both papers and code implementation controlled by 'reset_after' in keras.

Comment: The difference in hidden state equation with one being opposite of another can be seen in these two pics, https://classic.d2l.ai/_images/gru_3.svg, https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Gated_Recurrent_Unit%2C_base_type.svg. Both seem to be correct and achieve the same thing but with different values, I will ask on cross validated to be sure.